# Jquery included as static resource is not working in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

I am trying to use jquery datepicker in the page.I have zipped the necessary file `jquery-1.8.0.min.js,jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css` and uploaded it as static resource. But the datepicker is not working.

I have named the file as JqueryTest in static resource.The main zipped folder name is JqueryFile-->The JqueryFile has 2 foldes-->js and css.

Visual force page

```
  <apex:page controller="check_Format" sidebar="true" showChat="true" >
 <head>
 <apex:includeScript value="   {!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryTest,'JqueryFile/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js')}" />
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryTest,'JqueryFile/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js')}" />
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryTest,'JqueryFile/css/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css')}" />
 </head>
 <script>

  var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();


 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<apex:form id="theForm">

 <body>
 <div class="demo">
  <p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text" /></p>
  </div>
 </body>


 </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

Where i am doing wrong?Please suggest.

In console i am getting the following error

[image]

Thanks.

error:-$ is not a function

[image]

Comment: are you receiving any jquery error in console or firebug?

Comment: Hi nitin,
Thanks for your quick reply,i have included the error snapshot above.

Comment: You are defining jQuery as j$ yet you are using $ in your function. Simply change $ to j$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to implement jquery picklist and

I have added static resource in my google drive Just download and add into your static resource.. make sure your static resource name `JQueryTest`

Download link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PMI0wQcOqlcVcwczZMWGFiLUk/view?usp=sharing

```
 <apex:page  sidebar="true" showChat="true" >
 <head>
      <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryTest,'/css/jquery-ui.css')}" />
      <apex:includeScript value="   {!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryTest,'/js/jquery-1.10.2.js')}" />
      <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryTest,'/js/jquery-ui.js')}" />

 </head>
 <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker-13" ).datepicker();
            $( "#datepicker-13" ).datepicker("show");
         });
      </script>
<apex:form id="theForm">

 <body>
 <div class="demo">
  <p>Enter Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker-13"/></p>
  </div>
 </body>


 </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

[image]

Use this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_datepicker.htm

---

### Change the Background Color of jQuery Datepicker

Use this css.. And change color based on your preference

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-datepicker {
    background: #333;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    color: #EEE;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the extra  from your code.

```
<script>

  var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

<!--remove this script tag-->
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: There also seems to be error in your jquery UI. Please use a correct version of the jquery UI.   Copy and save in the static resource from the below link:  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js

Comment: Hi nitin,
I need minified version of jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js....The link you have provided is it same?

Comment: Use this then http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: i added the new js file now i am getting different error.I have uploaded the snapshot above

Comment: remove this line var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 0):

Use 'jQuery' object reference instead of '$' to avoid conflicts between SFDC and JQuery JS scripts.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

it does not work in my enviroment by now .
finally I found there are two mistake in my environment 
firstly the zip file and my resource name not be consistent.[image]
secondly the url in the visualforce page must include the resourcename
like /resourcename/****.js.